# Ошибка в когах discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Нашел туториал, как сделать коги в discord.py, понял принцип сижу пишу, дохожу по последнего штриха в bot.py и тут встречает в консоли такая ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте отредактировать вопрос и вставить Ваш код как код, а не как картинку. А то ведь минусовать вопрос будут...

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Вам вместо `extension` надо написать `filename`

```
for filename in os.listdir("./cogs")
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
```